# Doctrine aggregated/virtual column

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Last week I started using Doctrine and I'm very positive about it, but I run into some problems. I am implementing the Hierarchical Data in MySQL: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html and the entity that I have needs some aggregated (not sure if this is the correct term, maybe virtual is better). But I need two additional field, namely: Depth and ParentID. At the moment (with native query) I am getting these through sub-queries. The result of Doctrine is a array and I want to have an object.

This is the table structure that I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `ID` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LeftID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `RightID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

And three example categories:

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`ID`, `Name`, `LeftID`, `RightID`) VALUES
  (1, 'cat#1', 1, 4),
  (2, 'cat#2', 5, 6),
  (3, 'cat#1.1', 2, 3);
```

I looked at the aggregated fields example from doctrine (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html), but it is not clear to me about the real implementation. Also if it is the same as what I want.

The entity I'm using at the moment looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Application\Entity\CategoryRepository") 
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $ID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $Name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $LeftID; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $RightID;
}
```

I am using magic setter/getter to expose protected properties (__set & __get), to receive the data I am using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    node.ID,
    node.Name,
    node.LeftID,
    node.RightID,
    (
        SELECT 
            ID 
        FROM 
            Category subtree 
        WHERE 
            subtree.LeftID < node.LeftID 
        AND 
            subtree.RightID > node.RightID 
        ORDER BY 
            subtree.RightID - node.RightID ASC 
        LIMIT 
            0, 1
    ) AS ParentID, 
    (
        SELECT 
            (COUNT(parent.ID) - 1)
        FROM 
            Category AS node, 
            Category AS parent 
        WHERE 
            node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID 
        AND 
            node.ID = 3
        GROUP BY 
            node.ID 
        ORDER BY 
            parent.LeftID
    ) As Depth
FROM 
    Category As node,
    Category As parent
WHERE 
    node.ID = 3
AND
    node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID
GROUP BY 
    node.ID
```

The result (with the given dataset) will be:

```
ID  Name    LeftID  RightID     ParentID    Depth   
3   cat#1.1     2   3           1           1
```

This is exactly the result that I want to have in the Doctrine entity, but cannot find a solution to get the entity as an Doctrine object. At the moment I have double functions, one giving back arrays where I really need the Depth and ParentID, and if I need the object I use the default doctrine functions (e.g, find), but I want to have a single elegant solution. Also, I think I will need this in the future with other object, for example: Age for a Person (calculated from Birthday).

Comment: I just lived this problem today. I couldn't really fix it, but I'm still looking for answer. I tried what you linked "Aggregate Fields" method, but the problem I found was the need of adding an extra field to table and that leads to a bad DB schema. If you found the answer I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer to this too. After using SQLAlchemy for so long, trying to work with PHP ORMs feels like punching myself in the face. Some of the most basic things that I took for granted seem to be completely impossible in Doctrine. Even propel is able to handle virtual columns, but every solution i've seen for this problem involves "Oh, just count() the related entities" or something equally unrelated to the question that was originally asked.

I've been looking for an answer to this for a week now, and it's driving me absolutely crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want (might need to tinker with it a bit):

```
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $manager->createQueryBuilder();
    $expr = $qb->expr();

    $query = $qb
        ->select('node.ID, node.Name, node.LeftID, node.RightID')
        ->addSelect('
            (SELECT 
                ID 
            FROM 
                Category subtree 
            WHERE 
                subtree.LeftID < node.LeftID
                AND
                subtree.RightID > node.RightID 
            ORDER BY 
                subtree.RightID - node.RightID ASC 
            LIMIT 
                0, 1) AS ParentID
        ')
        ->addSelect('
            (SELECT
                (COUNT(parent.ID) - 1)
            FROM 
                Category AS node, 
                Category AS parent 
            WHERE 
                node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID
            AND
                node.ID = 3
            GROUP BY 
                node.ID 
            ORDER BY 
                parent.LeftID
            ) As Depth
        ')
        ->from('Category', 'node')
        ->join('Category', 'parent')
        ->where($expr->eq('node.ID', 3))
        ->andWhere($expr->between('node.LeftID', 'parent.LeftID', 'parent.RightID'))
        ->groupBy('node.ID')
        ->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Edit: Nevermind. Just noticed that you need an object, not an array...

You might want to look into either this Doctrine extension: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md

Or, as an alternative, create a new object class with the fields you need, mark it as readOnly for Doctrine and create custom queries for it (you can read up on using virtual tables with Doctrine).